# How can I prevent a click event from executing the same query when the triggering link is clicked twice in a row

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a click event that executes a query on a database table and is supposed to trigger a different alert depending on the length of the object that query returns. The query checks a table to see if a user has already stored their user info in relation to a particular object id. The id represents an event. I want to prevent a user from storing their info for the same event twice. So when the link is clicked the first time, the query checks the table to see if their info has already been saved in relation to that event id, if it hasn't, it stores their info along with the event id; but when that link is clicked for a second time, I want to alert a message telling the user they have already submitted their info. For some reason when I test it, the conditional doesn't work the second time around, meaning when the link is clicked twice in a row, the message telling the user they've already stored their info doesn't alert.

```
$("#mainDiv").on('click', '.interested', function (event) {
    //get id attribute of the clicked "interested" link. It stores the id of the activity.
    var activityID = $(event.target).attr('id');

    /*instantiate object that will hold info about interested user. The constructor function and variables are declared in a different part of my code*/
    var intrstd = new interested(hood, gender, dateOfBirth, zip, uID);

    /*check the "Interested" table on Parse to see if the user already has info stored for this activity */
    var check = Parse.Object.extend("Interested");
    var interest = new Parse.Query(check);

    //these are query constrains that pick out the colum values I want. 
    interest.equalTo("parent", activityID);
    interest.equalTo("InterestedPPL", intrstd.uID);

    //interest.find() executes the query and "results" contains the return object
    interest.find({
        success: function (results) {
            /*if the user info is already saved for the specific id, show the alert, if not store the object containing their user info */
            if (results.length !== 0) {
                alert("you have already requested an invite to that activity");
            } else {
                var show = Parse.Object.extend("Interested");
                var int = new show();
                int.set("parent", activityID);
                int.set("InterestedPPL", intrstd);
                int.save();
                alert("you will be notified if you have been invited to this activity");
            } //closes else   
        },
        error: function (object, error) {
            // The object was not retrieved successfully.
            // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
            console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    }); //closes find
}); //closes on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable `_clickFlag` outside the event handler. Process the event if `_clickFlag` is *true*. Before running the query, set it to *false* so that consecutive clicks are not processed. In your query success callback, set `_clickFlag` back to *true* again. This method has an advantage. It won't make extra queries at all. Hope I'm clear enough. Refer to below code sample.

```
var _clickFlag = true;
$("#mainDiv").on('click', '.interested', function(event){

    if (_clickFlag) {// Continue only if true

        _clickFlag = false; // this is to prevent other consecutive clicks to be processed when
        .
        .
        .

        interest.find({ success: function(results) {

            var show = Parse.Object.extend("Interested");
            var int = new show();
            int.set("parent", activityID);
            int.set("InterestedPPL", intrstd);
            int.save();

            _clickFlag = true;

            alert("you will be notified if you have been invited to this activity");
    .
    .
    .
    .
```